# Is running a state for threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, state

I was going through java documentation and found that running is not a state for threads. But I found some articles on the web which say that running is a state. So is running a thread state in java or not?

Reference : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Comment: All the states are listed in the link you provided - what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `RUNNABLE` is the state of a thread when its running.

From the javadoc you linked:

> A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:
>
> ```
> RUNNABLE
> A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
> ```

A note on RUNNABLE from the javadoc:

> A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual
>   machine but **it may be waiting for other resources from the operating
>   system such as processor**.

Comment: and RUNNABLE does not mean _RUNNING_ How many of the runnable threads are actually running depends on how many processor resources you have..

Comment: @P.J.Meisch True enough, and even though it is considered as running within the JVM it is a whole lot harder to work out if the processor is actually running the code. I have added the note from the java doc to my answer.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, a thread in RUNNABLE state could be either ready to run or may be actually running

Comment: Check the javadoc you linked: A thread in the RUNNABLE state is always ***executing/running*** in the java virtual machine. Any other state means that it is not currently executing in the java virtual machine.